# AS3 Center Video in StageVideo

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, centering, stagevideo

I've a brief question that I'm sure some AS3 genius knows.

I'm surprised I haven't seen any other topics on this after 30 minutes of Google-fu, StageVideo seems to be largely silent.

So I've been trying out the StageVideo API in place of traditional Videos for better video playback. This is for a Flash video streamer I am creating. While I'm quite certain the only videos I'll be using it for are 16:9, I'd like for it to be versatile enough to handle other aspect ratios. So for those other ratios, how do I center the video that's shown in the StageVideo object? I just want it to be letterboxed - no scaling, zooming, or cropping.

Changing the viewPort stretches the video to fit it, which is not what I want. And the videoHeight & videoWidth properties are read-only, so it's not like I can just change those to force the video to sit back. I read on the documentation that the video aligns to the stage's top-left, maybe I can change this?

Can I center videos in StageVideo? Is this not possible, and if so, must I use a regular Video object?

Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: You'll need to add a resizeHandler and bind it on a `videoStateChangeEvent`. In this handler you position the video.

Comment: @AndreLehnert Where is the `videoStateChangeEvent` located? I've tried looking for it in `StageVideoEvent`, `Event`, and `VideoEvent`. There also do not seem to be any reference docs for `videoStateChangeEvent` on the Adobe website

Comment: Sorry, long time didn't use StageVideo. I meant ´StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE´.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't see this - I just needed to change the start x & y of the Rectangle for the viewPort. Guess I forget how Rectangles worked briefly.

Comment: If you had posted your code, we had looked at it ;-)

Comment: @AndreLehnert Yeah :) I had no idea it was that simple though, I thought I was missing like 20 lines of code or something